# Should it be [pinescript-v5] or [pine-script-v5]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are currently 3 tags for the TradingView Pine Script (TM) language.

- [pine-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pine-script)
- [pine-script-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pine-script-v4)
- [pinescript-v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pinescript-v5)

Note the inconsistency. Also, the official documentation for the language (all versions) calls it "Pine Script"; i.e. two capitalized words. Given that spaces may not be used in tag names, the first two tags are a natural mapping of the official name to a tag name.

Should [pinescript-v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pinescript-v5) be renamed to [pine-script-v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pine-script-v5) to be consistent?

Comment: Sure. This is sensible and trivial.

Comment: [It seems](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Versions.html) to be [unevenly edited](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjC4D1jJkgY&t=14s&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFUOPyA8aLONTz5jr-IQFu5&index=22). For example, is "Pine" a shorthand for "Pine Script"?